# Count number of a specific characters in a string in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am using report builder and SSRS to create a report that needs to count the number of a given character  in a string. I have looked for a function that might do this to no avail. Is there a way to pull this off?

---

```
StringCount("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog","o")
```

---

This function should return 4 for the **o** in br**o**wn, f**o**x, **o**ver, and d**o**g.

Answer (score 2):

So there isn't a quick and easy function that does exactly what you want, but there is a way to do this in SSRS using `LEN` and `REPLACE`.  So to test, I made a simple dataset with just two fields, one value each.  The first is a string of random letters and the second uses your example sentence.

```
SELECT 
   'AAABBBCCCWWWLLLaaaoooSSSEEEWWW', 
   'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' AS QuickFox
```

The expression will use `REPLACE` to replace the desired character with nothing in the string.  You can then subtract that value from the full length of the string to get the correct count. This also uses `UCASE` to catch both upper and lower case variations.

```
= LEN(Fields!QuickFox.Value) - LEN(REPLACE(UCASE(Fields!QuickFox.Value),"O",""))
```

To finish this more fully, you could take in a parameter or a field and apply the `UCASE` function.  This should get you an accurate count of all possible instances of a letter in a given string.

```
= LEN(Fields!QuickFox.Value) - LEN(REPLACE(UCASE(Fields!QuickFox.Value), UCASE(Parameters!CharToSearch.Value),""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex combined with LEN to do this.

The following is based on having two report parameters, one is the string to search and the other is the character to search for. You may need to modify to suit your purpose but the principle is sound.

```
=LEN(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace
(UCASE(Parameters!SearchThis.Value)
, "[^" + UCASE(Parameters!searchChar.Value) +"]"
, ""
))
```

Notes:

1. RegEx is not one of my strong points so there may be cleaner ways to do this...
2. If you want a case sensitive search, remove the UCASE statements